# TypeScript login

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

Buenas necesito ayuda con typescript. Intento hacer un login con bcrypt usando su metodo CompareSync para comparar la contraseña enviada con la contraseña guardada en la base de datos pero me suelta un error.

```
    import { Request, Response, Router } from 'express';
import User from '../models/User';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

class LoginUser {
    public router: Router
    constructor() {
        this.router = Router();
        this.routes();
    }

    private async userLogin(req: Request, res: Response) {
        let body = req.body
        const userdb = await User.findOne({name:body.name});

        bcrypt.compareSync(body.password, userdb.password)
    }

    routes() {
        this.router.post('/api/login', this.userLogin);
    }


}

const apiLogin = new LoginUser();
export default apiLogin.router;
```

Ese es mi codigo. En la linea donde hago la comparacion me dice que el argumento userdb es de tipo Document o Nulo y no se puede asignar como parametro de tipo string, y al hacer el .password me dice que esa propiedad no existe en esa variable.

> Editado

[image: errores]

Tambien agregue lo de encryptar las contraseñas. Me sirve a la perfeccion, tambien intente hacer el if para comprobar. Intente Try-Catch y es el mismo error para todo. Segun yo, debe ser un problema con algun type en los campos.

Comment: a ver.. lo de userdb.password te dice que puede ser nulo, porque tiene razon, User.findOne, podria devolver nulo, entonces te pide que antes de usarlo te fijes si no es nulo. Lo otro, es que body, de un request, no tienen un campo password. De que campo de body estas hablando?

Comment: req.body me refiero a lo que lo puedo enviar. En estos momentos uso postman para ir probando, body = req.body, ahi almaceno todo los campos que puede recibir entre eso un password.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo lo siguiente:

1). Antes de comparar la imagen prometo valides si la petición a la base de datos con find() es te devuelve algo si no tienes la posibilidad de que te dé el error que te da.

2). Si te devuelve el usuario pasa el contenido de la contraseña a una variable por ejemplo...
let passwordDB = dbuser.password;

3). Encripta la contraseña nueva que ha introducido el usuario.

4). Compara con un simple IF las 2 contraseñas si las 2 son las mismas y esta de igual forma encriptadas tendrá que pasar la validación correctamente.

De esta maneras no tendrías margen de error por que tienes todos los huecos cubierto, espero haberte sido de ayuda un saludo.

Comment: Que va. Sigue el mismo error. No puedo seleccionar el password porque segun no existe. Pero acabo de comprobar haciendo una consulta tipo get al objeto que me trae el User.findOne y si me trae todo el usuario que le pido. Soy nuevo en typescripts y no logro comprender el porque de este error.

Comment: Sube una foto de lo que te devuelve porfavor para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Acabo de notar que es un error de consola solamente. Es decir, a pesar de que me marca error, funciona. Acabo de probarlo, hago la consulta y si loguea perfectamente, hasta me retorna el token (Jwt) del usuario. Y las comparaciones tambien funcionan pues escribo un password que no existe y me retorna error de compatibilidad. Pero sigo sin entender el porque me marca error en la consola y el editor.

Comment: Intenta primero validar que el usuario esté correcto y luego casa la contraseña así y me dices que tal. userdb[“password”]